# When using java runtim.exec to ssh, how do I get console output of that remote machine?

Tags: java, ssh, stdout, runtime.exec

Say we have this method to make an ssh to another machine. How would I get the output from that machines terminals back to the host machine

```
  public void getSSHreply()
  {
    Process p;

    // Set up the arguments for ProcessBuilder
    String[] cmd = 
    {
        "/usr/bin/ssh", 
        "someRemoteMachine", //This machine will authenticate with keys, hence no pw needed
        "./myprog",
    };

    try
    {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

            //How would I redirect stdout back to host machine?
            StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer();
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

            while (input.readLine() != null) 
            {
                 s.append(input.readLine() + "\n");
            }

            System.out.println(s.toString());


    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
            System.err.println("Failed to read & or start ");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`Process`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) object has methods for getting the `STDOUT`, `STDERR`, and `STDIN` streams. (ex. `getOutputStream()`).

You may want to look into [commons-exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/) for more convenient ways to launch and manager external programs, which has tools like [`StreamPumper`](http://commons.apache.org/exec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/exec/StreamPumper.html) to redirect data.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't. The simplest way is probably to read p's inputStream and errorStream (normally in two separate threads).

I believe your immediate problem is because you are using a BufferedReader - so when SSH displays the "Password: " prompt (which doesn't have a terminating line feed) Bufferedreader won't be returning anything to your input.readLine() call.

The easiest thing is to read the input a single character at a time (though not the most efficient, of course).

You'll also probably want to read the stderr stream as well, which is why you might want a couple of threads.

Comment: Can you go into this a bit? This is something I've wanted to do as well before...

Comment: I dont need password I authenticate with keys